# QScrollArea inside QGroupBox, scrollbars instead of resizing QGroupBox

Tags: c++, qt, qscrollarea, qgroupbox

I want to have a QScrollArea inside QGroupBox, so when I add new widgets to group box its size stays the same, but I have scroll bars instead of resizing group box itself.

Here's my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <QGroupBox>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGroupBox *box = new QGroupBox(QObject::tr("Example"));
    QScrollArea *sa = new QScrollArea;

    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
    QPushButton *b1 = new QPushButton("A");
    QPushButton *b2 = new QPushButton("B");
    QPushButton *b3 = new QPushButton("C");
    QPushButton *b4 = new QPushButton("D");
    QPushButton *b5 = new QPushButton("E");
    QPushButton *b6 = new QPushButton("F");
    QPushButton *b7 = new QPushButton("F");
    QPushButton *b8 = new QPushButton("F");
    QPushButton *b9 = new QPushButton("F");

    // addWidget(*Widget, row, column, rowspan, colspan)
    // 0th row
    gridLayout->addWidget(b1,0,0,1,1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(b2,0,1,1,1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(b3,0,2,1,1);

    // 1st row
    gridLayout->addWidget(b4,1,0,1,1);

    // 2nd row with 2-column span
    gridLayout->addWidget(b5,2,0,1,2);

    // 3rd row with 3-column span
    gridLayout->addWidget(b6,3,0,1,3);

    gridLayout->addWidget(b7,4,0,1,3);

    gridLayout->addWidget(b8,5,0,1,3);

    gridLayout->addWidget(b9,6,0,1,3);

    box->setLayout(gridLayout);
    sa->setWidget(box);

    setCentralWidget(sa);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

What I have now is that every time I add a new QPushButton, QGroupBox resizes, no matther there is a QScrollArea. What should I change to have the behaviour I want? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are putting the groupbox inside the scroll area. Scroll area doesn't restrict its childrens size.

You should do the opposite, put scrollarea inside group box. Here is how;

```
QWidget* sw = new QWidget();
sw->setLayout(gridLayout);
sa->setWidget(cont);
QVBoxLayout* bl = new QVBoxLayout(box);
bl->addWidget(sa);

setCentralWidget(box);
```

Note that if you are using toggle buttons (such as radio button) they will not act as a group. Because technically they are not in the same QGroupBox any more - they are inside the scroll area. You can provide group behavior using a `QButtonGroup` instance.

Comment: Changedit as you suggested: http://pastie.org/private/n18c4xrsruu693io9x8r6g but still, there's no scroll bars available. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `setCentralWidget(sw);` -> `setCentralWidget(box);`

Comment: Thank you. But is it possible to have, lets say, 2 or 3 `QGroupBox`es one next to another on a grid layout, with `QScrollArea` inside? Somehow I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Since you will have multiple instances of it, I suggest you to create a new class that inherits `QGroupBox`, make modifications required for scroll bar as part of this class. That way it will be much easier and cleaner.